# Too many sessions in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am building an **E-commerce** website on ruby on rails from scratch.(This is my first project on ruby on rails)

My product belongs to a subcategory which in-turn belongs to a category.

My filters partial include **multiple check-boxes** for category,subcategory,additional_category(Like hand made clothes,factory built etc.),lifestyle(relaxed,corporate etc) and cloth_material_type(this has around **30 options**)

I am sending **5 arrays** for each of these cases to the backend to search through the associations.

**Now when a non logged in user reloads the page the filters set by user resets to default**.

To avoid this I have four options in mind.

**Option 1**. Store the filter values set by the user in the **cookies** which is fast.But it might slow down the user's browser.

**Option2** . Store the values in a session using **ActiveRecord::SessionStore** gem which will increase the size of session for me to 65K but would slow down the application.

**Option 3** .Using jquery **modify/create document.url** options so that every filter option gets appended to the document.url and on reload I get the parameters set by the user for filtering.But this looks very cumbersome to implement.

**Option 4**. Using gems like **rails temporary database** etc.

I have opted with option 2 and using session store for the purpose but I think that it will become cumbersome to maintain this in the future.

Just need some suggestions like what do other rails ecommerce websites do to solve this problem or is there any better way to solve this.

Comment: I would use url parameters since one of the tenets of restful design is that a  resource should look the same regardless of browser state. So if I'm looking at pink ladies shoes and copy paste the browser url and send it to a friend they should see the same selection.

Comment: You could of course use this together with cookies / guest user accounts to remember favorites. But building a URL oriented solution usually ends up being more robust due to the statelessness.

Comment: Thanks for your response.N exactly what worries me..in addition to these arrays i have price range and custom stitch options available. I am planning to create a search model for temp data.So that the user can easily save them if they want to and share their saved searches. And adding a cronjob to a rake task to delete the stale tuples in search model and session model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Redis**

What I'd do is add a layer of abstraction; specifically I think you'd benefit from using `Redis`, or similar *temporary db* (as you alluded to in your question).

[Redis](http://redis.io) is a `key:value` database, which basically stores JSON values for you to use within your app. If you tie it to a model, you'll be able to store temporary values without hindering your app's performance.

I think you could setup Redis to store a guest id, and an array of your values from that:

```
[guest_user_id] => [
    1 => "x"
    2 => "y"
    3 => ["z", "a", "b"]
]
```

You'd be able to generate the `guest_user_id` when you initialize the `Redis` system, and store it in the user's `session`. This way, you're only storing minimal data inside your user's browser, and can populate the various controller actions with `Redis` data:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :categories do
   resources :subcategories
end

#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.new_data
       # create guest_id and send to Redis
    end
end
```

This will allow you to populate a session with your `guest_id` *if* the user is not registered:

```
#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @user = user_signed_in? ? current_user : User.new_data
        #You'll then be able to populate their Redis values with the data from the product selection etc
    end
end
```

I could go into more specifics, but as you're only looking for suggestions, this is what I have to recommend at the moment

Comment: Thanks a lot for the valuable suggestion.I found another way- using HTML5 local storage with which you can save around 5 MB of data on client side.(The only downside being many users would be working with legacy browsers) .Marking your answers as a solution, adding a layer of abstraction would surely be helpful in many ways :)